# How to find the area of the shaded region?

Tags: geometry, area

How do i find the area of the following shaded region?

The figure consists of two circles, one of radius $2r$ and the other of radius $r$.

The distance of the center of the circle of radius $r$ from  the bigger circle is $r$, as shown.

The total angle is $\theta$---$\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take a Cartesian reference in the center of the small circle, so that
$$
x^2+y^2=r^2\\
(x+r)^2+y^2=(2r)^2
$$
are the equations of the two circles, then in polar coordinates the two equations reduce to
$$
\rho=r\\
\rho=r\left(\sqrt{3+\cos^2\phi}-\cos\phi\right)
$$
The requested area is given by
$$
A=\int_{-\theta/2}^{+\theta/2}d\phi\int_r^{r\left(\sqrt{3+\cos^2\phi}-\cos\phi\right)}\rho d\rho
$$

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

Represent the shaded region as an algebraic sum ($+$- and $-$- signs) of circular sectors and triangles.